# A balanced coin is tossed three times. Define the events: Are events $A, B, C$ mutually independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A balanced coin is tossed three times. Define the events

$A=$the same result is obtained in the first toss and second toss.

$B=$the same result is obtained in the second toss and third toss.

$C=$the same result is obtained in the third toss and first toss.

Are events $A, B, C$ mutually independent?

My answer is no, since $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=1/2$ and $P(A\cap B\cap C)=1/4$, then $P(A\cap B\cap C)\neq P(A)P(B)P(C)$

Comment: I agree with you. If they were independent the intersection probability would be $1/8.$ But note you did not ask a question. Maybe should at least add you are asking for validation of your conclusion.

Comment: it depends on which specific independence you are requested, they're *pairwise independent* while not being independent independent. I'd guess *mutually independent* is probably the normal one, in which case your argument is true.